# Why is Node.js's version so low?

Tags: node.js, express

I've been watching the development of Node.js and frameworks like Express for a while. I finally found some time to play around and am enjoying it.

Does anyone know why Node's current version is only 0.10.0?  I know it doesn't really matter but it makes it seem like an extremely new and unstable project when in fact it seems that it's being used quite a bit and even by some big players.

Comment: This question isn't really a [good fit](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for this site, but you may want to read [this recent official blog post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/03/11/node-v0-10-0-stable/#enterprise).

Comment: No, it is not that low. If you compare to other languages it is still young. But its good enough to run in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it *is* new, it's only been around since 2009.

That may seem old to you whippersnappers but I primarily program in a language from the '70s and sometimes on machines that have been around since the '60s.

But seriously, it probably has more to do with the numbering scheme than any *actual* immaturity. As you can see [here](http://nodejs.org/dist/), there have actually been quite a few releases.

If you wait a little while, the [release plan](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/03/11/node-v0-10-0-stable/#enterprise) calls for a `0.12` (code cleanup mostly) to be followed by `1.0` which, based on comments, will be the "final" product (though there will still be more versions since predictions aren't perfect). Many projects start with a (crappy) `1.0` and improve that. The philosophy for node.js seems to have been to approach `1.0` as the fully-polished end product.

Comment: does that mean that node.js development will be drawing to close after 1.0 target is reached?

Comment: @chovy: no, from the release plan: : "New versions will still come out, especially to pull in new versions of our dependencies, and bugs will continue to be fixed. There's been talk of pinning our release cycles to V8, and automating the release process in some interesting ways".